# Is it possible to use a ethernet switch to provide two different routers with the same internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, switch

Say I wanted to created two networks. One for the more privileged group of people. The restrictions on this network would be less severe. Then the other network would be for the "guests" or those deemed unworthy of the unrestricted network. Could I connect the switch to the cable that comes from my ISP and then connect the two routers to the switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and No. It is possible to have one internet connection for multiple networks, however each router will need its own public IP address. You would need to check with your ISP to see if its possible to obtain multiple IPs.

Answer (score 1):

If your router supports multiple "Virtual Interfaces," you won't need to have two routers. If you use or install [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) on your router, you can create a virtual interface for your guests and enable AP Isolation to keep that traffic separate from your "trusted" network.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean the cable that comes out the wall.. from your telephone company.. that goes to a modem.

You wouldn't/couldn't use a basic switch to isolate two parts of a network.. but a more advanced switch that does VLANs might. I haven't used one but I am pretty sure it(a switch that can do VLANs) can isolate two parts of a network.  (there is such a thing as a layer 3 switch but as I understand it, that's a router).

A device that does the function of Router and firewall can have two networks and restrict traffic between them.  I'd guess that most routers (as in routers that don't have modems in them), would be reasonably advanced as routers letting you define subnetworks, and they'd have a firewall in the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use small server as router and make as many virtual interfaces as you need.

Answer (score -1):

As others have said, your scenario only works if the ISP allows you two IP addresses. Usually this requires extra fees. Many newer routers have a guest wifi function that allows guests to attach, and is the easy way if that suits your needs.

Another way to accomplish what you're suggesting is to eliminate the switch and connect the guest router to the ISP, then connect the privileged network router to one of the ports on the guest router. The privileged network would be protected from the guest network, but not vice versa.